# WCF and MSMQ hosting in IIS issues

Tags: wcf, iis-7, msmq

I have a WCF service that talks to MSMQ. When I run the service in VS2010’s service test client interface it can place the messages in the proper queues and everything is fine. When I host the WCF service in IIS7 and call the service from my web application all the messages go into the Transactional dead-letter queue.

I setup the application pool and site (the site hosting the WCF service) with identities that I know have specific access to the queues.

Is there something else I can check or that I am doing wrong?

Update:
Well, I think there is something else going on. I created a SUPER simple service that can read and write from the queues without fail. I jsut need to dig deeper and find out. Thanks to everyone who has looks, but I will keep this open so I can report back or if someone may have other ideas. I know it is hard to determine without viewing any code, but it is difficult to post becuase i have a lot to break apart.

Comment: It would help if the configuration is explained. For example, is the MSMQ local to the machine where the WCF is hosted? If not, which MSMQ has the messages in dead letter?

Comment: Yes, the WCF service is on the same machine as MSMQ. I specifed the Transactional dead-letter queue as the queues where the messages are going. the queues are setup as non-transactional and the messages are setup to be non-transactional.

Comment: What kind of naming is used to name the queue in the code? Could you post that (mask the actual name with something generic but keep the exact format). The description of the problem indicates that the queue is treated as remote queue and the MSMQ is not able to find the remote queue and thus delivering the message in the transactional dead-letter queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the guys who coded the queue did not setup the queues correctly.

Answer (score 0):

set the ExactlyOnce = false either in code or in your client app.config file.

like this

```
NetMsmqBinding binding = new NetMsmqBinding(NetMsmqSecurityMode.None);
binding.ExactlyOnce = false;
```

Hope this will solve the problem.

Cheers
Naushad